# Cell that counts based on both row and column using unique identifiers

Tags: excel, countif

So I am creating a sign-up sheet where if someone enters their name from a pull down list it will count the number of times their name appears depending on what is in the first column of the template.

It looks something like this:

```
WEEK 1 (Merged Cell from A:F)
          10/1     10/2     10/3    10/4     10/5  
Primary   PersonA  PersonD  PersonB PersonD  PersonE
Secondary PersonC  PersonA  PersonC PersonA  PersonB
WEEK 2 (Merged Cell from A:F)
          10/8     10/9     10/10   10/11    10/12  
Primary   PersonE  PersonE  PersonB PersonE  PersonA
Secondary PersonA  PersonD  PersonC PersonC  PersonD
```

And this repeats

So I would like to populate a table which counts three things:

1. How many primaries someone is scheduled for
2. How many secondaries someone is scheduled for
3. How many times they are scheduled at all in the last three columns (so D:F)

Since they are all using a pull down I would like the table to look like:

```
Name     Primary    Secondary   Weekend
PersonA  2          3           2
PersonB  2          1           3
PersonC  0          4           3
PersonD  2          2           2
PersonE  4          0           2
```

So I hope to COUNTIF based on the identifier on column A for primary and secondary and just rely on the number of times the name appears in the last three columns. It's also worth noting that sometimes there are weeks with 2 primaries and one secondary and vice versa.

Comment: What have you tried, `COUNTIFS()` may work, no?

Comment: yes and no, I need to nest countifs with conditionals if that makes sense however I'm getting nowhere still

Comment: Where do you get the "Weekend" info?  Also are those dates actual dates, just formatted as `mm/d`?

Comment: "Weekend" is just the final three columns

Comment: is this MS Excel or Google Sheets?

Comment: Google sheets  '